# literal object and jquery selectors DRY

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a case where I want to do this:

```
var els = {
    div: $('div'),
    p: els.div.find('p'),
    span: els.p.find('span')
};
```

But this happens:

```
console.log(els.div); // Works
console.log(els.p); // undefined
```

So I'm currently doing this:

```
var els = (function(){
    var div = $('div'),
        p = div.find('p'),
        span = p.find('span');
    return {
        div: div,
        p: p,
        span: span       
    }
}());

console.log(els.p); // Works now
```

Is there any way I can make it DRYer? Seems like a bunch of code to just be able to do that.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could build it step by step:

```
vars els = { div: $('div') };
els.p    = els.div.find('p');
els.span = els.p.find('span');
```

Or like this:

```
vars els = { };
els.div  = $('div');
els.p    = els.div.find('p');
els.span = els.p.find('span');
```

if it seems more consistent to you.

Comment: Why does this work and my code doesn't? It's just an object what's the difference that makes it work this way?

Comment: @elclanrs: You should get an error with yours (http://jsfiddle.net/ambiguous/uFxeh/) since `els.div` isn't defined until you hit the closing `}`; `els` is only partially formed while you're still defining it (so it is `undefined` and doesn't have any properties: http://jsfiddle.net/ambiguous/VDuTw/) and you haven't finished defining it until you hit the closing brace.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to just do something like this, right?

```
var els = {
    div: $('div'),
    p: this.div.find('p'),
    span: this.p.find('span')
};
```

I used the `this` keyword instead of `els` inside the object.

Answer (score 0):

To take this one step further, you could employ the [Factory Pattern](http://addyosmani.com/resources/essentialjsdesignpatterns/book/#factorypatternjavascript) to handle the object creation for you.

```
function getChildElements(container, childTags) {
    var elements = {};

    // Default tags to find if none were specified.
    childTags = childTags || [ "p", "span" ];

    // Loop through the childTags and find them in the container
    childTags.forEach(function (tag) {
        elements[tag] = container.find(tag);
    });

    return elements;
}
```

Clients can make use of this factory method to retrieve child elements from a parent like so:

```
var els = getChildElements($("div"));
```